# reducing the number of markers when plot with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf

There are too many markers on the line, how could I only plot few of markers?

**Figure:**
[image]
**Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.58824,0.58824,0.58824}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.89412,0.10196,0.10980}%
\definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.21569,0.49412,0.72157}%
\definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.30196,0.68627,0.29020}%
\definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{1.00000,0.49804,0.00000}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.521in,
height=3.539in,
at={(0.758in,0.508in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=3000,
xtick={   0,  500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000},
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={X},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={Y},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor4, dashed, line width=2.0pt, mark=square, mark options={solid, mycolor4}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
50  0.9834264\\
100 0.974296\\
150 0.9648184\\
200 0.9529258\\
250 0.9410852\\
300 0.9304922\\
350 0.920181\\
400 0.9098856\\
450 0.9005352\\
500 0.8908822\\
550 0.8804412\\
600 0.867324\\
650 0.8567086\\
700 0.8448816\\
750 0.8282384\\
800 0.8195136\\
850 0.8067574\\
900 0.7918128\\
950 0.7785728\\
1000    0.7620058\\
1050    0.7464702\\
1100    0.7249504\\
1150    0.7063224\\
1200    0.686981\\
1250    0.663326\\
1300    0.6409518\\
1350    0.6151574\\
1400    0.5793994\\
1450    0.5536608\\
1500    0.5244878\\
1550    0.4909266\\
1600    0.452572\\
1650    0.419305\\
1700    0.3855892\\
1750    0.3481886\\
1800    0.3107104\\
1850    0.2804826\\
1900    0.248753\\
1950    0.223371\\
2000    0.1922176\\
2050    0.171771\\
2100    0.1519022\\
2150    0.13144\\
2200    0.113525\\
2250    0.0949822\\
2300    0.0790246\\
2350    0.0656442\\
2400    0.0598496\\
2450    0.0489776\\
2500    0.0411896\\
2550    0.03396\\
2600    0.0285898\\
2650    0.0242706\\
2700    0.019216\\
2750    0.0153486\\
2800    0.0130666\\
2850    0.0091866\\
2900    0.0079618\\
};
\addlegendentry{my line}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not want to reduce the number of the points, just want to plot few markers, e.g. only 10 markers on the original line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: with `mark repeat` section 4.7 Markers, Linestyles, (Background) Colors and Colormaps

Old answer

In section 4.22 Skipping Or Changing Coordinates – Filters in th pgfplots's documentation

With `x filter/.expression` or `x filter/.code`

for example `x filter/.expression={mod(x,100)==0 ? nan : x},`

```
  \documentclass[tikz,boreder=1cm]{standalone}
  \RequirePackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}%<< this line
  \begin{document}
  % This file was created by matlab2tikz.
  %
  %The latest updates can be retrieved from
  %  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
  %where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
  %
  \definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.58824,0.58824,0.58824}%
  \definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.89412,0.10196,0.10980}%
  \definecolor{mycolor3}{rgb}{0.21569,0.49412,0.72157}%
  \definecolor{mycolor4}{rgb}{0.30196,0.68627,0.29020}%
  \definecolor{mycolor5}{rgb}{1.00000,0.49804,0.00000}%
  %
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
  width=4.521in,
  height=3.539in,
  at={(0.758in,0.508in)},
  scale only axis,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=3000,
  xtick={   0,  500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000},
  xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  xlabel={X},
  ymin=0,
  ymax=1,
  ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
  ylabel={Y},
  axis background/.style={fill=white},
  axis x line*=bottom,
  axis y line*=left,
  xmajorgrids,
  ymajorgrids,
  legend style={at={(0.03,0.03)}, anchor=south west, legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
  ]
  \addplot [
  % x filter/.expression={mod(x,100)==0 ? nan : x},%<< this line
  color=mycolor4,
  dashed, 
  line width=2.0pt, 
  mark=square, 
  mark options={solid, mycolor4},
  mark repeat={10},%<< this line
  ]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
  50  0.9834264\\
  100 0.974296\\
  150 0.9648184\\
  200 0.9529258\\
  250 0.9410852\\
  300 0.9304922\\
  350 0.920181\\
  400 0.9098856\\
  450 0.9005352\\
  500 0.8908822\\
  550 0.8804412\\
  600 0.867324\\
  650 0.8567086\\
  700 0.8448816\\
  750 0.8282384\\
  800 0.8195136\\
  850 0.8067574\\
  900 0.7918128\\
  950 0.7785728\\
  1000    0.7620058\\
  1050    0.7464702\\
  1100    0.7249504\\
  1150    0.7063224\\
  1200    0.686981\\
  1250    0.663326\\
  1300    0.6409518\\
  1350    0.6151574\\
  1400    0.5793994\\
  1450    0.5536608\\
  1500    0.5244878\\
  1550    0.4909266\\
  1600    0.452572\\
  1650    0.419305\\
  1700    0.3855892\\
  1750    0.3481886\\
  1800    0.3107104\\
  1850    0.2804826\\
  1900    0.248753\\
  1950    0.223371\\
  2000    0.1922176\\
  2050    0.171771\\
  2100    0.1519022\\
  2150    0.13144\\
  2200    0.113525\\
  2250    0.0949822\\
  2300    0.0790246\\
  2350    0.0656442\\
  2400    0.0598496\\
  2450    0.0489776\\
  2500    0.0411896\\
  2550    0.03396\\
  2600    0.0285898\\
  2650    0.0242706\\
  2700    0.019216\\
  2750    0.0153486\\
  2800    0.0130666\\
  2850    0.0091866\\
  2900    0.0079618\\
  };
  \addlegendentry{my line}

  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this case, the curve will be changed since the number of points was reduced.

Comment: With `mark repeat` I have update my answer